# How to implement 'stress-free' boundary conditions (stokes flow)?

Tags: boundary-conditions, navier-stokes

I have to implement 'stress-free' boundary conditions for a stokes flow of a 2D-domain (for the left, bottom and right boundaries). The boundary condition are also described mathematically as $2 \eta \dot{\epsilon} = 0$. $\eta$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$ are the viscosity and strain rate.

How do I implement such boundary conditions? Would stress-free mean that for the left/right boundary the velocities are: $\frac{\delta v_x}{\delta x} = \frac{\delta v_y}{\delta x} = 0$? And for the bottom: $\frac{\delta v_x}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta v_y}{\delta y} = 0$?

Comment: That depends on your discretization scheme. In general, indeed, the gradients should vanish at the boundary.

Comment: I am using finite elements...so in that case I don't have to implement any boundary condition, since 'stress-free' conditions are based only on Neumann conditions. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you describe the physical problem briefly? For the left and right boundaries, $\frac{\delta v_x}{\delta x}= 0$ will make the boundary an "outflow". Do you want fluid flowing out at the boundary? $ \frac{\delta v_y}{\delta x} = 0$ is sufficient to set the tangential shear stress at the boundary to zero.

Comment: At least two of the comments above are wrong. It's not the normal component of the gradient that is vanishing, but $n \cdot \dot\varepsilon$ that is zero. Depending on your normal vector $n$, this will couple different derivatives of $u$.

Answer (score 1):

My take on boundary conditions for the Stokes equations are given [here](https://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_22.html). It also links to some video lectures that describe the procedure by which you arrive at it. The thing to note is that "stress-free" also involves the pressure.